# Problem with Laravel 8: Call to a member function count() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm a newcomer to Laravel, and I got errors when I tried to generate some info in the table in the database using a factory.

> Call to a member function count() on null " at
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/HasFactory.php:17.

Maybe somebody had the same problem? I will be grateful if someone can help. Below will be the code of certain elements:

**Seeder**

```
class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Users::factory()->count(30)->create();
    }
}
```

**Factory**

```
class UploadInfoFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Users::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'Name' => $this->faker->name,
            'Birthday' => $this->faker->date('d-m-Y'),
            'Phone number' => $this->faker->phoneNumber,
            'Phone balance' => $this->faker->numberBetween(-50,150),
        ];
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateInfoUsers extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('info_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integerIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->date('Birthday');
            $table->string('Phone number',100);
            $table->string('Phone balance',100);
        });
    }
}
```

The error code that pops up in bash when we enter php artisan db: seed:

```
Call to a member function count() on null at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/HasFactory.php:17
     13▕     public static function factory(...$parameters): Factory {
     14▕         $factory = static::newFactory() ?: Factory::factoryForModel(get_called_class());
     15▕ 
     16▕         return $factory
  ➜  17▕                     ->count(is_numeric($parameters[0] ?? null) ? $parameters[0] : null)
     18▕                     ->state(is_array($parameters[0] ?? null) ? $parameters[0] : ($parameters[1] ?? []));
     19▕     }
     20▕ 
     21▕     /**
```

Comment: have you setup the configuration for the `Users` model to know to use this `UploadInfoFactory`? as for this to automatically use a factory the factory would have to have a particular name

Answer (score 13):

This might help someone else cause my problem was different. When seeding the database, Laravel printed out the same error that @Yurii experienced.

```
Seeding: Database\Seeders\ProfileSeeder

   Error 

  Call to a member function count() on null

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/HasFactory.php:18
```

Indeed my `artisan` console failed to create the Factory for my Profile model

```php
$ php artisan tinker
>>> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
>>> Factory::factoryForModel(Profile::class);
=> null
```

After some minutes of investigation, I found out that I forgot to return the Factory in the `configure` method

```php
class ProfileFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Profile::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            // some stuff
        ];
    }

    public function configure()
    {

        // it miss the return here !!
        $this->afterCreating(function (Profile $profile) {
            // do stuff with $profile
        });
    }
}
```

So, when the Factory was instantiated, the `configure` method was called but no Factory was returned! Placing the return fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I switched to UUIDs and had commented out some of the model events in the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a model to automatically use a factory you would have to name the factory in a particular way, otherwise you would have to define a way to resolve the particular factory you want to use for the model.

Rename your factory to `UsersFactory` and it will automatically be used be the `Users` model.

Though, I suggest renaming `Users` to `User` as the convention is for models to be in the singular and tables to be in the plural. If you change the model name you would then need to change the factory to `UserFactory` to match.

> "The `HasFactory` trait's `factory` method will use conventions to determine the proper factory for the model. Specifically, the method will look for a factory in the `Database\Factories` namespace that has a class name matching the model name and is suffixed with `Factory`. If these conventions do not apply to your particular application or factory, you may overwrite the `newFactory` method on your model to return an instance of the model's corresponding factory directly"

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Database Testing - Creating Models Using Factories - Connecting Factories and Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will do that and also I will read this Laravel docs, I hope this will help me